# Column wise count in Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have this DF:

| A | B | C | D | COLUMNS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | ABC |  | 2,3 |
|  | DEF | ABC | DEF | 2,4 |
|  | LSD | LSD | LSD | 2,4 |
|  | ERR | ERR |  | 2,3 |
|  | ERR | ABC | LSD | 2,4 |

Expected Output

| A-1 | B-2 | C-3 | D-4 | F-5 | COLUMNS INDEX | ABC | DEF | ERR | LSD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | ABC |  |  | 2,3 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  | DEF | ABC | DEF | DEF | 2,4 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
|  | LSD | LSD | LSD | LSD | 2,3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
|  | ERR | ERR |  |  | 2,3 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
|  | ERR | ABC | LSD | LSD | 2,4 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I HAVE CREATED THE COLUMN INDEX FOR SUMMING BUT I COULDN'T ABLE TO LOOP EACH COLUMNS INDED AND GET THE INTENDED OUTPUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the relevant columns, then use a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to the original DataFrame:

```
s = df.drop(columns=['A', 'COLUMNS']).stack().droplevel(1)

out = df.join(pd.crosstab(s.index, s))
```

If you want to use the boundaries from the "COLUMNS" column, you can combine it with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) to build a mask:

```
import numpy as np

# build the mask
limits = df['COLUMNS'].str.split(',', expand=True).astype(int)
a = np.arange(df.shape[1])
m1 = (a+1>=limits[0].to_numpy()[:, None])
m2 = (a<limits[1].to_numpy()[:, None])

# apply the mask and stack
s = df.where(m1 & m2).drop(columns=['A', 'COLUMNS']).stack().droplevel(1)

# count
out = df.join(pd.crosstab(s.index, s))
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C    D COLUMNS  ABC  DEF  ERR  LSD
0  1.0  ABC  ABC  NaN     2,3    2    0    0    0
1  NaN  DEF  ABC  DEF     2,4    1    2    0    0
2  NaN  LSD  LSD  LSD     2,4    0    0    0    3
3  NaN  ERR  ERR  NaN     2,3    0    0    2    0
4  NaN  ERR  ABC  LSD     2,4    1    0    1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
a = df[['B','C','D']].melt(ignore_index=False)['value']

df1 = df.join(pd.crosstab(a.index, a))

df1.insert(4, 'F', df1['D'])
d = {v: f'{v}-{k}' for k, v in enumerate(df1.columns[:5], 1)}
df1 = df1.rename(columns=d)
print (df1)
   A-1  B-2  C-3  D-4  F-5 COLUMNS  ABC  DEF  ERR  LSD
0  1.0  ABC  ABC  NaN  NaN     2,3    2    0    0    0
1  NaN  DEF  ABC  DEF  DEF     2,4    1    2    0    0
2  NaN  LSD  LSD  LSD  LSD     2,4    0    0    0    3
3  NaN  ERR  ERR  NaN  NaN     2,3    0    0    2    0
4  NaN  ERR  ABC  LSD  LSD     2,4    1    0    1    1
```

If need slice by `COLUMN`:

```
from collections import Counter

L = [Counter(b[a[0]-1:a[1]]) for a, b in zip(df['COLUMNS'].str.split(',', expand=True)
                                                        .astype(int).to_numpy(), 
                                             df.to_numpy())]

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index).fillna(0).astype(int))
print (df)
     A    B    C    D COLUMNS  ABC  DEF  LSD  ERR
0  1.0  ABC  ABC  NaN     2,3    2    0    0    0
1  NaN  DEF  ABC  DEF     2,4    1    2    0    0
2  NaN  LSD  LSD  LSD     2,4    0    0    3    0
3  NaN  ERR  ERR  NaN     2,3    0    0    0    2
4  NaN  ERR  ABC  LSD     2,4    1    0    1    1
```

Comment: honestly, the is the exact same logic as I used… `melt` instead of `stack` explicit slicing instead of `drop`…

Comment: @mozway - I dont look for your solution. I use my how best I know.

Comment: Arent you supposed to use the `COLUMNS INDEX` column? The expected output is slightly different in both answers compared to whats in the question.

Comment: I guess the count should only consider values between the columns given in the `COLUMNS INDEX` and not all the columns.

Comment: @jezrael Can we add conditions inside the L variable like i need only the ABC and LSD columns alone ?? I need only few columns before joining it to the main df.

Comment: @EashwarGV - Yes, use `df.where(df.isin(['ABC','LSD'])).to_numpy()` instead `df.to_numpy()`